# Solr: Modify the log for dih request

Tags: logging, solr, log4j, dataimporthandler, dih

I am working on an application that uses solr as its search engine, I need to log the dih requests (with succeded & failed indexed documents).

Is there a way to modify the log directory for a dih request and the log file name?

thanks in advance...

**Edit:**

Finally, I managed to direct logging of the class "LogUpdateProcessorFactory" to a new location (a sub-directory in logs).
My problem now is:

- **I need to create a new log file for each dih request I send to solr**.

- **I need more information about indexing process: the file beeing indexed, whether it succeded or not, the cause af failures if exists**...

This is what I've added to the xml configuration file log4j2.xml:
In appenders:

```
'<'Routing name="DihLog">
    '<'Routes pattern="$${ctx:ROUTINGKEY}>
        '<'Route key="$${ctx:ROUTINGKEY}">
           '<'RollingFile name="DihFile" fileName="${solr.log.dir}\dih\dih_${date:yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm}.log" filePattern="${solr.log.dir}\dih\dih_%d{yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm}.log" >
               '<'patternLayout>'<'pattern>[%p] %c{1.} %m%n '<'/pattern>'<'/PatternLayout>
               '<'Policies>'<'TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy />'<'/Policies>
           '<'/RollingFile>
       '<'/Route>
   '<'/Routes>
'<'/Routing>
```

And In Loggers:

```
 '<'Logger name="org.apache.solr.update.processor.LogUpdateProcessorFactory" level="all" additivity="false">
        '<'AppenderRef ref="DihLog" />
    '<'/Logger>
```

Now, a dih file named by date is created & the messages of the class LogUpdateProcessorFactory are logged into it, but if tow requests are sent in a very short interval of time, they both are logged in the same file.

I appreciate any help.

Comment: you can do this directly on the admin interface in logging level dataimport. change the value null to whatever you want

Comment: on the admin interface I can only change the logging level, and not the logging location,also, these changes are not permanent...